# Why i can't work with service in any class in symfony4. DependencyInjection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I have a bundle Symfony4. 
I need to working with PostgresSQL with ORM Doctrine. I want to call some class(Service) to work with ORM, but i have a problem.

Tried to create 
a service in services.yaml and create class. Already tried use ContainerBuilder, but have this issue "The service "Event" has a dependency on a non-existent service "doctrine.orm.entity_manager". 
what am I doing wrong. In class which extends Controller i get EntityManger without problem. How to get EntityManager outside the Controller.

services.yaml

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
    Event:
        class: App\Core\Event
        public: true
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

App\Core\Event.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Core;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class Event
{
    public $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em) {
        $this->entityManager = $em;

    }
}
```

Any class where i want to get service

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder();
        $fileLocator = new FileLocator('/home/admin/web/noticer_service/public_html/config');

        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, $fileLocator);
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
        $container->compile();
        $container->get('Event')
```

Comment: You have autowiring enabled, you probably don't need to add anything to your `services.yaml` (unless you really know what you're doing).

Comment: Also, try to inject `\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager` instead, works for me.

Comment: Probably because you are new'ing the event object.  Does not seem like you are even using the framework for your posted code.

Comment: Don't understand exactly what do you mean. I need to replace EntityMangerInterface to ObjectManage? I tried to call any service in class and have same error. If i tried get service without arguments that works fine. And don't undestand about autowiring.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't undertood how to call Doctrine in another class

Comment: Show the place where you use your Event object. How you do that?